# Rails & Heroku: Automatically save a copy of data from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, etl

everyone

I have a small site running on free tier of heroku. It fetchs/updates data from various sources frequently, and I want to save a copy of the database (~10000 records) every month to somewhere else, so I can see how the data changes overtime, and make some more detailed analysis. The website is developed in Ruby on Rails.

I want to know

- What is the best practice of exporting data from heroku, esp. for Ruby on Rails apps? (~10000 records)
- Is there any good place to share this data with others? (i.e., Kaggle dataset, Github repo)

Thanks!

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR You’re better off building your own export script connecting to your instance and [using SQL dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/backup-dump.html). The hobby plan is very limited.

---

There are multiple backup strategies. For instance, if you require exporting once a month you could set up a cron job every 30 days that exports the data you desire.

Since you're using Heroku, they have a way to manage backups. To do so navigate to:

```
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/{your-app}/resources
Select your database add-on
Navigate to Durability
```

And there you should see the default backup strategy from Heroku. This is heroku’s daily strategy to modify this, [heroku toolbelt provides the following](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduling-backups):

```
heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at '02:00 America/Los_Angeles' --app sushi
```

but this would be daily backups.

Mind the following constraint:

> A monthly backup means that only 1 backup is saved over the course of a month. Based on current limits, for example, a Premium-0 would have 12 monthly backups, one for each of the last 12 months.

Also, if you decide to adopt Heroku’s built in approach, mind the following:

> There is a limit to the number of manual backups that you can retain. That number is based on your database plan.

```
Plan        Backups Retained
Hobby-Dev            2
```

Concerning sharing it, there are a few things to take into consideration; for instance, if the information is sensible (by default) we want a way to control who has access to the resource. There are ways to achieve this commercially using a private Github repo or even an amazon S3 bucket with ACL (Access Control List). [Heroku's dataclips](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips) may also be used but not sure you want this.